# How many ways can we color a $7$-cycle with $3$ colors so that no three consecutive nodes are of the same color

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I have to paint graph

[image: $7$-cycle]

We have three colors.  The constraint is that there are no three consecutive nodes of the same color.

And my idea is:

All ways to paint is $3^7$

I'm going to count following situations:

1. Exactly $7$ nodes have the same color - it is three possibilities.
2. Exactly $6$: $7 \times 3 \times 2$
3. Exactly $5$: $7 \times 3 \times 2$
4. Exactly $4$: $5(3 \times 2 \times 1+3 \times 2 \times 2 )$
5. Exactly $3$: $5 (3 \times 2 \times 2 + 3 \times 2 \times 3 + 3 \times 2 \times 2 + 3 \times 2 \times 2 + 3 \times 2 \times 2 + 3 \times 2 \times 3 ) $

Finally it yields:
$$3^7 - (1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5) = 1548$$

Is it correct? Maybe somebody has another approach?

Answer (score 3):

That number is not going to be correct: it counts e.g. `XXXYZZZ` twice and `XXXXYYY` 3 times.  It also fails a check: if we rotate a valid color combination, we always obtain a distinct valid color combination.  The [Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma)  therefore implies the number will be divisible by $7$.

---

To be honest, if I was going to answer this question, I would just plug it into a computer.  Here's some [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
S:=Tuples([1,2,3],7);;
A:=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,1],[7,1,2]];;
T:=Filtered(S,L->ForAll(A,I->Size(Set(I,i->L[i]))<>1));
Size(T);
```

which gives $1134$ colorings.

---

But if we really want to do it by hand, it can be done.  We begin with all $3^7$ colorings.

- Exactly one color: we exclude $3$ color combinations.
- Exactly two colors: The partitions of $7$ into $2$ parts are $(4,3)$, $(5,2)$, $(6,1)$.

  - Case 43: There are $3 \times 2=6$ choices for these colors, and once chosen they can be arranged as `XXXXYYY`, `XXXYXYY`,  `XXXYYXY` or one of their cyclic rotations.  So we exclude $6 \times 3 \times 7=126$ possibilities here.
  - Case 52: We have structures `XXXXXYY`, `XXXXYXY` and `XXXYXXY`.  There's $3 \times 2=6$ ways to choose the colors, and $7$ rotations.  Thus giving $3 \times 6 \times 7=126$ possibilities here.
  - Case 61: We have the structure `XXXXXXY`.  There's $3 \times 2=6$ ways to choose the colors, and $7$ rotations.  Thus giving $6 \times 7=42$ possibilities here.
- Exactly three colors:  The partitions of $7$ into $3$ parts are $(3,2,2)$, $(3,3,1)$, $(4,2,1)$, and $(5,1,1)$.  So we do the bookkeeping:

  - Case 322: We have the structure `XXX----`.  There are $3$ ways to choose the colors (since the `Y`s and `Z`s are equinumerous), and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to assign the `Y`s and `Z`s, and $7$ rotations.  Thus giving $3 \times \binom{4}{2} \times 7=126$ possibilities here.
  - Case 331: We have structures `XXXYYYZ`, `XXXYYZY` and `XXXYZYY`.  There's $3!$ ways to choose the colors, and $7$ rotations.  Thus giving $3 \times 3! \times 7=126$ possibilities here.
  - Case 421: We have structures `XXXXYYZ`, `XXXXYZY`, `XXXXZYY`, `XXXYXYZ`, `XXXYXZY`, `XXXXZYY` `XXXYYXZ`, `XXXYZXY`, `XXXZYXY`.  There's $3!$ ways to choose the colors, and $7$ rotations.  Thus giving $9 \times 3! \times 7=378$ possibilities here.
  - Case 511: We have structures `XXXXXYZ`, `XXXXYXZ`, `XXXYXXZ`.  There's $3!$ ways to choose the colors, and $7$ rotations.  Thus giving $3 \times 3! \times 7=126$ possibilities here.

Finally, we do the arithmetic: $$3^7-3-(126+126+42)-(126+126+378+126)=1134$$ agreeing with the computational result.